# How would you shorten this query?

Tags: mysql, join

I know it's kinda specific, but I can't figure out how to make it simpler.  It involves multiple joins and multiple tables.  This gives the desired result, but is ugly as hell.

Here is what I've got.  there HAS to be a better way than all these joins, especially the multiple joins of the same tables, however every other variation takes WAY too long to produce the same results.

```
SET @SEARCH:="toxic +crystal";
SELECT i.itemName item, id1.preview, it.isIngredient, it.hasRecipe, i2.itemName ingredient, id2.preview, it2.hasRecipe, ri.count AS needed, MATCH(i.itemName) AGAINST(@SEARCH) score
FROM recipe_detail rd
JOIN item_detail id1 ON id1.item_id = rd.output_item_id
JOIN recipe_ingredients ri ON ri.recipe_id = rd.recipe_id
JOIN item_detail id2 ON id2.item_id = ri.item_id
JOIN itemNames i ON i.itemId = id1.item_id
JOIN itemNames i2 ON i2.itemId = id2.item_id
JOIN items it ON it.item_id = i.itemId
JOIN items it2 ON it2.item_id = ri.item_id
WHERE MATCH(i.itemName) AGAINST(@SEARCH)
ORDER BY score DESC, id1.item_id;
```

If more details are needed, just ask.

By ugly, I more or less meant simplify, as I'm trying to expand this query to be "recursive"  to find the entire ingredient chain (and amounts needed, but that's another issue). I'd rather fire it off in one query since doing it via php script seemed to take too long as well. Just trying to optimize it.

I could omit the itemNames join and do that from the script with another query, but I'm trying to figure out how to do it all in one shot.  I'm starting to think it's not possible.

(some non-relevant fields omitted)
example data
items:

```
item_id |  hasRecipe  |   isIngredient
--------------------------------------
  1              N               Y
  2              N               Y
  3              Y               Y
  4              Y               N
```

recipe_ingredients:

```
recipe_id |  item_id  |  count
------------------------------
  1             2          2
  1             3          1
  2             1          4
```

recipe_detail:

```
recipe_id | output_item_id
--------------------------
   1             4
```

The final goal of this is to allow someone to select an item, and get a hierarchical display of what all is needed to create that item, thus why I'm trying to trim things down to possibly use a recursive-ish (@var method I guess) query to pull it in one shot then parse it.  The longest result could be upwards of 10 or 12 steps to get there.

Comment: What's wrong with that query?  If it works and isn't causing problems then leave it as it is.

Comment: Can you show example data and expected output?

Comment: What do you mean by "ugly"? Please use language that actually describes what the *problem* is.

Comment: That query looks as simple as it can get. If you need to join different rows in `items` with `item_detail` and `recipe_ingredients`, multiple joins is the only way to do it.

Comment: Query looks pretty simple. Blimey if I show you some I handle at work, and the time they take to execute. I don't think you can simplify that query any more.

Comment: post the results of an EXPLAIN...

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: I failed to explain that this was just the beginning of it, I was hoping to simplify it before moving on with it.  see addition.

Comment: @Yisera this is going in the back end of a search query, so making it fast as i can is somewhat important.

Comment: Like the answer below says, query against the view, that's a good method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use a view.

```
CREATE VIEW view_name_goes_here AS 
SELECT i.itemName item, id1.preview, it.isIngredient, it.hasRecipe, i2.itemName ingredient, id2.preview, it2.hasRecipe, ri.count AS needed, MATCH(i.itemName) AGAINST(@SEARCH) score
FROM recipe_detail rd
JOIN item_detail id1 ON id1.item_id = rd.output_item_id
JOIN recipe_ingredients ri ON ri.recipe_id = rd.recipe_id
JOIN item_detail id2 ON id2.item_id = ri.item_id
JOIN itemNames i ON i.itemId = id1.item_id
JOIN itemNames i2 ON i2.itemId = id2.item_id
JOIN items it ON it.item_id = i.itemId
JOIN items it2 ON it2.item_id = ri.item_id
```

Then you can just select against the view.

Comment: Although my final version wound up being lots different (did an annoying recursive function that might wind up here too) querying against the view helped tons for the final output.  Thx, don't know why i didn't think of it.